# PWA opens Safari on POST. Is there a way to make it not?

Tags: mobile-safari, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I'm working on converting an existing app to a PWA. Part of that PWA deals with POST from a login form with a redirect to another page. In Safari, if you open the app from the home screen and try to log in, it opens a new tab in Safari. I would love this not to happen.

I've tried just return-ing on a POST and caching the redirected page. It seem to work for a bit but then would return to it's old ways. I've debugged through the code and it seems to switch once it gets a response back from the fetch. Here's my fetch handler

```
  if ((e.request.cache === 'only-if-cached' && e.request.mode !== 'same-origin') || (e.request.type === "POST") {
    return;
}

e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request)
        .then(function (response) {
            //Cache Hit

            // IMPORTANT: Clone the request. A request is a stream and
            // can only be consumed once. Since we are consuming this
            // once by cache and once by the browser for fetch, we need
            // to clone the response.
            var fetchRequest = e.request.clone();

            return fetch(fetchRequest).then(
                function (response) {
                    //Check to see if we are valid
                    if (!response || response.status !== 200 || response.type !== 'basic') {
                        return response;
                    }
                    // IMPORTANT: Clone the response. A response is a stream
                    // and because we want the browser to consume the response
                    // as well as the cache consuming the response, we need
                    // to clone it so we have two streams.

                    var responseToCache = response.clone();

                    caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
                        .then(function (cache) {
                            cache.put(e.request, responseToCache);
                        });
                    return response;
                })
        }))
```

I expected that Safari wouldn't open up but it does and I'm all out of ideas on how to fix this.

Comment: A couple questions / thoughts: Does the new tab open when you do this without PWA? How / why do you re-direct?  Would you consider replacing the form post on the logon page with an AJAX post?  Good luck.

Comment: The new tab doesn't open when there isn't a PWA involved. We use web forms apsx page for our login and use "Response.Redirect" in the codebehind and we want to redirect to the dashboard page, And, I'd have to clear it with my boss before I did anything with changing the login

Comment: I see, good info re:Response.Redirect.  It's a tricky spot to have to fix the logon without changing it.  Seems like investigation into how Safari handles redirects from PWA may be best.  If you can't control Safari, doing the logon from an AJAX call could be a 2nd way to logon, and you could keep your existing method unchanged, but any security change would need approval in a big org.